# setTimeout for automatically Title-Update

Tags: refresh, shoutcast

currently i'm programming a little Radio-Station which is using Shoutcast.

The code is generelly working but i'm stuck in updating for example the songtitle if the track is changing.

So what i've done is putting that script in the header of my main .php file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
function load_update() {
    $('#update').load('update.php', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            load_update();
        }, 1000);
    });
}
```

There is also a line to output the information:

```
<div id="update" ><?php include('update.php') ?></div>
```

And i created a update.php:

```
<?php
echo $file = simplexml_load_file('http://admin:PASSWORDISHERE@IPISHERE/admin.cgi?sid=3&mode=viewxml&page=5');
?>

<div class="Titel" style="text-align: center;"><span class="Titel">    <?php       echo  $file->SONGMETADATA[0]->TIT2, '<br />'; ?></span></div>
<div class="Titel" style="text-align: center;"><span class="Interpret"><?php        echo  $file->SONGMETADATA[0]->TPE1, '<br />'; ?></span></div>
```

As already said, the Code is working but not updating the Songtitle if i change the Track. It just stays. If there were other methods to do this please leave an answer.

var_dump($file) displays following:

> object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) { ["SONGMETADATA"]=>
>   object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (10) { ["TIT2"]=> string(16) "Feel this
>   Moment" ["TALB"]=> string(24) "Club Sounds Best of 2013" ["TPE1"]=>
>   string(32) "Pitbull Feat. Christina Aguilera" ["TYER"]=> string(4)
>   "2013" ["COMM"]=> string(1) "." ["TCON"]=> string(4) "Club" ["TENC"]=>
>   string(31) "SHOUTcast Source DSP v2.3.3.201" ["TRSN"]=> string(15)
>   "www.test.com" ["WORS"]=> string(24) "http://www.shoutcast.com"
>   ["extension"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (2) { ["title"]=> array(2)
>   { [0]=> string(51) "Pitbull Feat. Christina Aguilera - Feel this
>   Moment" [1]=> string(51) "Pitbull Feat. Christina Aguilera - Feel this
>   Moment" } ["soon"]=> string(51) "Pitbull Feat. Christina Aguilera -
>   Feel this Moment" } } }

Comment: What does `var_dump($file)` show you?

Comment: Answer is in the first Post.